# React: Saving mapping in select

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

Tell me, please, how to save the selected value of `option`, at me in a `select` it is saved only first value (which is `One`).How to save the selected value in `select`?

Here is the code (this is `final-form`):

```
export const SelectFilter = props => {
  const { onFilterChange, filterOptions } = props;
  return (
            <Form
              render={({ handleSubmit }) => (
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                  <div>
                    <label htmlFor="section">Select:</label>
                    <Field
                       id="section"
                       name="section"
                       component="select"
                       onChange={e => onFilterChange(e)}
                       defaultValue={filterOptions.section}
                    >
                      <option value="one">One</option>
                      <option value="two">Two</option>
                      <option value="three">Three</option>
                    </Field>
                  </div>
                </form>
              )}
            />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I typically handle all forms in react. This will allow it to be reusable, by letting you pass down the submit functionality :D
You can also pass the onChange functionality if that's really what you wanted to do

```js
class GalleryFilter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentValue: "one"
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let {
      value
    } = e.target;
    this.setState({
      currentValue: value
    });
  }

  submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.Submit(this.state.currentValue);
  }
  render() {
    return ( <
      form onSubmit = {
        this.submit
      } >
      <
      div >
      <
      label htmlFor = "section" > Select: < /label> <
      select id = "section"
      name = "section"
      component = "select"
      onChange = {
        this.onChange
      }
      value = {
        this.state.currentValue
      } >
      <
      option value = "one" > One < /option> <
      option value = "two" > Two < /option> <
      option value = "three" > Three < /option> <
      /select> <
      /div> <
      /form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It is necessary to make it on my example and with my data, instead of to copy the code from any resource

Comment: I need a solution to the problem only with my data, not another code

Comment: Look at how I did the onChange and how you did it. You're calling onChange in a wier way. Also, look at how I wrote it

Comment: `onChange={this.onChange}`

Comment: and only with final-form

Comment: `let { value } = e.target;` Value is the select options value

Comment: it works on the site, I just need to keep the current value in the select (value={e.target.value})

Comment: Where are you trying to keep it? I need more info

Comment: Yes. Thats where you can store that value. typo. I fixed it on mine.
That will work to hold your information in the element

Comment: your code is without final-form and me interesting solution of the problem only with my code (not another code and not another data)

Comment: Gotcha. Will post another answer

Comment: I can not use a class, only in my example you can add, not write another code

Answer (score 0):

This should work the same way

```js
export const GalleryFilter = props => {
  const { onFilterChange, filterOptions } = props;
  var currentSelection = "one";
  
  function onChange(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    let {value} = e.target;

    currentSelection = value;
    onFilterChange(e);
  }

  return (
            <Form
              render={({ handleSubmit }) => (
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                  <div>
                    <label htmlFor="section">Select:</label>
                    <Field
                       id="section"
                       name="section"
                       component="select"
                       onChange={onChange}
                       value={currentSelection}
                    >
                      <option value="one">One</option>
                      <option value="two">Two</option>
                      <option value="three">Three</option>
                    </Field>
                  </div>
                </form>
              )}
            />
  );
};
```

Comment: onChange={e => onFilterChange(e)} - this line can not be touched

Comment: That line is still being fired. Just in a different place.

Comment: `onFilterChange(e);` at the bottom of onChange

Comment: Post error please. There is more than likely another bug in your code. What sort of problem do you get?

Comment: version with `var currentSelection = "one";` does not fit, I have three interrelated `select`s, code can not be changed

Comment: Please post a screen shot of the error you are getting.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/ww40y2m595 - here you can try to save the value

Comment: look `Favorite Color`

Comment: I took the code for the select from this example (codesandbox.io/s/ww40y2m595), it works, but does not save the value

Comment: Where are you trying to save the value? You need to give more information on the problem. Please revise your question

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding the point of React Final Form. It looks like you're trying to keep track of which value is selected manually in `state`, but that's exactly what React Final Form does for you.

If you want to see what value is currently selected in the select, you can either look at `values.section` in the prop given by `<Form>`.

[Here's a demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ww40y2m595).